# Slim aways show 404 error page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp, http-status-code-404, slim

I'm trying to test Slim on my Mac under XAMPP or native Apache Server from MAC OS, but  under anyone works. Follow the code:

```
<?

require 'Slim/Slim.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get('/', function () {
    echo '<h1>Sample test!!!</h1>';
});

// POST route
$app->post('/post', function () {
    echo 'This is a POST route';
});

// PUT route
$app->put('/put', function () {
    echo 'This is a PUT route';
});

// DELETE route
$app->delete('/delete', function () {
    echo 'This is a DELETE route';
});

$app->run();

?>
```

Look at GET function callback just prints H1 text.

My .htaccess content:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
#
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I didn't change anything in original files that I got at Slim website and keep showing 404 error on browser!

Could somebody help me?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was usign a 5.2.x version instead of 5.3.x!